# How to wait till webViewDidFinishLoad gets completed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa, ipad

I have a boolean condition that initializes a webView, and in webViewDidFinishLoad loads another delegate to fire once the completions is done. However, since the boolean returns prior the condition "webViewDidFinishLoad", the page never gets fully loaded. How can I make sure webViewDidFinishLoad gets loaded prior the boolean condition?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

use this property of webview to check

```
 @property(nonatomic,readonly,getter=isLoading) BOOL loading;
```

Comment: @Saad, can I use this? while ([webby isLoading]) {
            wait(1000);
        }   Not sure if I put some function within while statement, as its just a dummy wait till it completes and then return True.

Comment: yes you can use as this is a bool but the body u are saying is not correct. cz u don't know on which plateform your app will run. if the cpu of that decvice is too fast then it will fail and if the cpu is too slow, then user will have to wait a great

Comment: Thats true, can you think of any scenario to utilize this properly? Thanks.

Comment: one thing is to use this [self performSelector:@selector(displayResults)
           withObject:nil
           afterDelay:2.0];

Comment: NSDate *future = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0.06 ];
[NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];