# iOS how to tell when webViewDidFinishLoad has completed?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have some code inside the webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method, and I need some way to tell that this code has finished executing from within another method in a completely different part of my code.  Is this possible?  Basically what I want to do is something like this:

```
-(void) myMethod
{
    // do stuff that causes webViewDidFinishLoad to be called

    if (webViewDidFinishLoad has finished executing)
    {
        // do stuff with outputString
    }
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    outputString = [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"myJSFunction('%@')",jsInputString]]; 
}
```

I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10531146/1525229) already and it made no sense to me.

I should add that inside myMethod, I can be sure that webViewDidFinishLoad will only be called once.

Comment: I consider that when one finds the need to block the main thread waiting for a delegate or notification, that is kind of a code smell. What are you trying to accomplish exactly? Perhaps there is another way to approach your problem.

Comment: Carl, my webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method contains a call to stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString. I need the result of that call before I can continue with the code inside myMethod.

Comment: Then don't call myMethod until after the web view has finished loading, if that's possible. If its from user input disable associated controls until after load. Will that work?

Comment: Argh, you're right.  I can split the action in myMethod into two methods, one which does stuff before the webView loads, and one which does stuff after the webView loads, and simply call the latter method from within webViewDidFinishLoad after I have my javascript string.  Thanks...I think I need sleep...

Comment: Haha, no problem :) I'll add it as an answer to the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid waiting for delegates and notifications in other methods - do the work that depends on them when they call back to your class. Don't call `myMethod` until you get the delegate message. If `myMethod` is called from user input, disable the associated controls until after the web view loads.

Answer (score 2):

You can always set a boolean to indicate whether the webview has finished loading.
And the value of the boolean will be changed in the webview delegate method:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    loadFinished = YES;
}
```

Then in your own method, check "loadFinished" will do the task.
You have to set `<UIWebViewDelegate>` for interface to use this delegate method

Answer (score 0):

- You could use `UIWebView`'s iVar `loading`
- You could use your own shared boolean flag as iVar and set it in `webViewDidFinishLoad`.

However, maybe you could reconsider your design and do in `webViewDidFinishLoad` what to do after loading is finished.

Answer (score 0):

Why not try GCD?

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    // WebView load content here 

    dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

       // load myMethod

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use a Boolean and set its value to `YES` in the last line of `webViewDidFinishLoad`.

then check in your `myMethod` like this:

```
-(void) myMethod
{
    // do stuff that causes webViewDidFinishLoad to be called

  if (yourBoolean == YES)
  {
      // do more stuff
  }
}
```

that should do your work.

Answer (score 0):

In webViewDidFinishLoad, you post a notification to your "myMethod" code part.
Something like this:

in UIWebView:

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"webview_finished" object:self userInfo:nil];
}
```

in your "myMethod" code part:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMethod) name:@"webview_finished" object:nil];
}
```